# Filtering Lines To Display

Tags: vim

I've used `:v/pattern/d` to filter the lines vim displays.

Now with the cursor on one of those lines I would like to undo the filter (show all lines in the file) but leave the cursor on the line where I left it.   Does that make sense?

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: If there's no complex scroll and view tasks, maybe `:g/pattern/` is enough. (no syntax highlighting may be a problem)

Answer (score 0):

From vim doc:

> Note that when text has been inserted or deleted the cursor position might be
> a bit different from the position of the change.  Especially when lines have
> been deleted.

Your problem is exactly in this case. After your `v/pat/d`, those lines has been removed. the changelist/jumplist won't remember the location on a removed line.

After you `undo` it, even if you press `ctrl-o` or double<kbd>`</kbd>, you won't go back to the deleted line, instead, you go the closest undelete line of the old cursor position.

If you want to go back to the deleted line after a undo precisely, you may set a `mark` before your `v/../d` after your undo, you can go back to the position by <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: Ok thanks.  Just completely new to vim.  I didn't realize /d was deleting lines yesterday.  :vimgreap with copen does much of what I want to do.